# Image of an injective complex function of an open set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be an **open** subset of $\mathbb C$ and let $f:U\to \mathbb C$ be an **injective** complex function. Is it true that $f(U)$ is open? I guess not, but I can not find a counter example. What if $U$ is also connected? Does then $f(U)$ is open? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, “complex function”? Need it be continuous? Smooth? Holomorphic?

Comment: Do you mean holomorphic functions? Because then it's true. But holomorphy is a very strong condition which the vast majority of complex functions don't fulfill.

Comment: Need not to be either continuous, smooth or holomorphic. Just injective.

Comment: A sufficient condition would also be that the inverse of $f$ is continuous. And if the statement were true in general, then injectivity would imply that the inverse of $f$ is continuous, which is clearly false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each open subset of $\Bbb{C}$ has cardinality equal to the continuum, and hence there will be an injective function mapping $U$ (injectively and surjectively) to the real line. Such a map will not be particularly simple to define, but $f(U) = \Bbb{R}$ is not open in $\Bbb{C}$ (regardless of whether $U$ is connected or not).